# Asp.net MVC - paypal ipn

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn

i am trying to integrate paypal sandox with my MVC project. I have enabled AutoReturn and ipn, i have disabled PDT.

After payment is made, in the auto-return page, i get

Request.HttpMethod --> GET
HttpContext.Request.ContentLength --> 0
Request.Form.Keys.Count --> 0

if i enable PDT also, i get the same result

can anyone please solve this

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're saying that your AutoReturn is issuing a GET with no parameters. Isn't this as designed? The AutoReturn is simply a redirect for the user, and doesn't necessarily need to contain any form parameters.

The IPN is what should be issuing you a POST. The IPN and AutoReturn URLs are two different values -- are both set up in your PayPal Manager?

Perhaps you could post some of your PayPal Manager settings/screenshots?

Comment: I understand it now. where can i find proper code to handle the get request in return url

Here, are the settings of the merchant test account
------

Auto Return: On
Return Url: http://www....../Order/ThankYou

Payment Data Transfer: On
Identity Token: qzYXRiKjEr2E1....

(Business Name: ddlak laks's Test Store, Account Type: Business, Status: Verified) --> details present in the overview page

Notification URL: http://website.......in/Order/Index
Message delivery: Enabled

--------

Comment: @dhanlak: So the IPN URL points to a controller/action called /Order/Index? Is that correct? If so, you need to edit your OrderController to add a new Index method (action) that accepts an HttpPost. To do this you simply put [HttpPost] right above your Index method, so now you'll have two Index methods -- one that handles a GET and one that handles a POST. Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: @Pandincus Could you give any support for this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911050/paypal-ipn-integration-with-asp-net-mvc