# Make payment with Paypal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am building an e-commerce web site and I am down to the payments options. My first task is to link up the order with the Paypal API, however i've been looking for options for a few hours and I have no clues where to start.

I have checked this: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal
But I cannot fathom where to start, especially since it is using Web forms and I am only experienced with MVC.

Can anyone help me out? Thank you very much.

Comment: You better start from here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/    you need to understant how paypal works

Comment: I would say the tutorial you've got there is a very good place to start.  Start reading from "Integrating Paypal" The core functionality is not dependent on your choice of UI framework.

Comment: I'm reading what you have provided, @DmitryKvochkin, but for this page (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/), I don't understand how to make the call for the Token call and Api call. I'm using C#.

Comment: @HerveS if you only want to implement the paymant, that part is not important. This is the most important to understand: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need something MVC specific to aid your understanding of the PayPal integration then you could try this MVC tutorial.

[asp net mvc paypal integration](http://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/asp-net-mvc-paypal-integration/)

I do believe the tutorial that you have is also very good and worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the idea flow you should have in mind when implementing simple paypal payment:

On your view, add paypal payment button:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_create-pps-buttons/

Now keep in mind, that the users can change the values so, you have to implement Paypal IPN Listener:
https://mvcsamples.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Kona.Web/Controllers/PayPalController.cs

Inside listener logic, you verify if the payment is correct and then do what ever you have to.

---

If you get in trouble testing it from localhost: just check this link: [Paypal Ipn integration with asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911050/paypal-ipn-integration-with-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

For PayPal Express try [PayPalExpressCheckoutMVC-MultiItem](https://bitbucket.org/anthonydotnet/paypalexpresscheckoutmvc-multiitem)

Comment: Wow, I really like that! I'm going to delve in the solution. Is that kinda like a DLL that I had to my project, or do you suggest that I rather work from the solution to implement my own things?

Comment: I would add it as a project to your existing solution, then you can create a PurchaseController in your web project using the existing PurchaseController as an example.